# Unity in Native iOS App Crashes after Build

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

Struggled a lot to build Unity in Native app. Tried to sort out all the prebuild errors but after build when app run it crashes. Screen shot

[image: error image screen]

My AppDelegate code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen]. bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *mainVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainIdentity"];
    UINavigationController *naVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = naVC;
    self.unityController = [[UnityAppController alloc] init];
    [self.unityController application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions];

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: open `CrashReporter.mm` file  and search this func name `InitCrashHandling` then comment this line `#if ENABLE_CUSTOM_CRASH_REPORTER
 //   InitCrashReporter();
#endif` .

Comment: @ a.masri, thank you very much . It worked fine...please copy and paste in answer section,i will mark it right so in future others can use

Comment: my answer added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this steps

1 - Open `CrashReporter.mm` in classes file

2 - search this func name `InitCrashHandling`

3- comment this line

```
#if ENABLE_CUSTOM_CRASH_REPORTER 
// InitCrashReporter(); 
#endif
```